# Select drop down value is not changing?

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

Here I am trying to change drop down value on click of button. But it is not working.

Could you please help me?

```js
// set option by value - select "option 2"
$('#btn').click(function() {
  $('#post-display-preference-select').val('2');
});
```

```css
.btn {
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 25px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table width="100%">
    <tr>
      <td align="center" style="font-size:14px;">

      </td>
      <td align="right">
        <select id="post-display-preference-select">
          <option value="1" selected="selected">Today</option>
          <option value="2">Last Week</option>
          <option value="3">Oldest</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<button id="btn" class="btn">Select "Option 2"</button>
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0n74x7ht/).

Comment: Have you included the jQuery library?

Comment: I am using jQuery v1.11.1

Comment: I don't see it in your jsfiddle.

Comment: Code in your question please.

Comment: @showdev is correct, you just need to include the jQuery library in the fiddle and it works fine.

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic due to a typo.

Answer (score -1):

```
You didn't select jquery in your jsfiddle
```

Try this one:

```
 https://jsfiddle.net/0n74x7ht/3/
```